# Convert monthly data to weekly data - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
ID Date     Volume Sales
1  2020-02   10     4
1  2020-03   8      6
2  2019-12   6      8
2  2019-10   4      10
```

Data here is monthly, and I would like to convert it to weekly.. dividing the volume and sales column by the number of weeks in the month.

I have tried to this but have only been successful doing this column by column.. is there an easy way to do this, that could also be handled on a large dataset.

Would it be a similar step in converting weekly back to monthly?
Thanks!

Comment: you can make use of `df.columns` attribute and you can apply same logic over multiple columns like for your current dataframe you can use `df[df.columns[2:]]=df[df.columns[2:]]/7`

Comment: Please add the minimum reproducible code snippet so that your problem can be solved

Comment: you can use `df.resample()` with appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you can try creating an array of all weeks based on the `Date` column using `pd.offset`, then explode and `groupby+transform` to get count of each group for using it in division:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
u = (df.assign(Weeks=[pd.date_range(*x,freq='W')
                  for x in zip(s,s.add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd()))]).explode("Weeks"))

u[['Volume','Sales']] = u[['Volume','Sales']].div(
                        u.groupby("Date")['Date'].transform("count"),axis=0)
```

---

```
print(u)

   ID     Date  Volume  Sales      Weeks
0   1  2020-02     2.5    1.0 2020-02-02
0   1  2020-02     2.5    1.0 2020-02-09
0   1  2020-02     2.5    1.0 2020-02-16
0   1  2020-02     2.5    1.0 2020-02-23
1   1  2020-03     1.6    1.2 2020-03-01
1   1  2020-03     1.6    1.2 2020-03-08
1   1  2020-03     1.6    1.2 2020-03-15
1   1  2020-03     1.6    1.2 2020-03-22
1   1  2020-03     1.6    1.2 2020-03-29
2   2  2019-12     1.2    1.6 2019-12-01
2   2  2019-12     1.2    1.6 2019-12-08
2   2  2019-12     1.2    1.6 2019-12-15
2   2  2019-12     1.2    1.6 2019-12-22
2   2  2019-12     1.2    1.6 2019-12-29
3   2  2019-10     1.0    2.5 2019-10-06
3   2  2019-10     1.0    2.5 2019-10-13
3   2  2019-10     1.0    2.5 2019-10-20
3   2  2019-10     1.0    2.5 2019-10-27
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. Question: Would this be the same logic to convert weekly to monthly data?

Comment: Can we do the same but not divide the volume and sales column by the number of weeks in the month? Is that possible? What should I change?